# Show that $h_n(x) = n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{1/2} \right)$ is measurable given that $f$ is measurable

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

I am trying to show that $h_n(x) = n \log\left(1+\left(\frac{f}{n} \right)^{1/2} \right)$ are Lebesgue-measurable function given $f$ a positive Lebesgue-measurable function.

I have a definition that says that $f$ is Lebesgue measurable iff $\{f < \alpha\}$ is measurable for every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$. So $\{h_n < \alpha\} = \{1+(\frac{f}{n})^{1/2} < e^{\alpha/n}\} = \{(\frac{f}{n})^{1/2} < e^{\alpha /n} - 1\} = \{f < n(e^{\alpha/n} - 1)^2\}$. Which I suppose that is measurable, because $f$ is. Is this procedure correct or is there a more straightforward way to show what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put it simply, in this case the composition of measurable functions is measurable.

For further reading: [here](https://heil.math.gatech.edu/6337/spring11/section3.5.pdf)

Comment: Link not working.

Comment: Strange, @PNDas. I just have opened it.

Comment: Indeed it's strange. @zkutch it's working now.

Comment: Now that I see that link, I think I could say that $g_n$ is a composition of a measurable and a continuous function, hence it is measurable, right? That would be simpler than what I did.